# How do I create a click event on a "Default Info Window(s)" based on the marker info for google maps v2, in xamarin android?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, infowindow

First of all I'm still new in Xamarin and I am trying to create a click event for a **default InfoWindow.** The thing is, using the code below under `MarkerOptions` (i.e. .SetTitle, .SetSnippet), will generate a default InfoWindow when I click on the marker, without creating or making any changes (custom InfoWindow) on xml.

**Marker info**

```cs
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(4.887746, 114.943652);
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
    .SetPosition(latlng)
    .SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.icon))
    .SetTitle("title1")
    .SetSnippet("address");

marker1 = gmap.AddMarker(options);

marker2 = gmap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .SetPosition(latlng2
    .SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.icon))
    .SetTitle("title2")
    .SetSnippet("address"));
```

However, my problem is that I don't know how to create a click event for each and every marker. For example, `marker1` will open `Activity1` and `marker2` will open `Activity2`.

My question is, is it possible for me to create a click event, for each and every marker info, based on a **default InfoWindow**? I did try out using the `OnInfoWindowClick` for a **Custom InfoWindow**, and it worked well. But I'm still wondering if it can be done using a **default InfoWindow**, generated from the code above.

I did check other forums and different sites and still couldn't seem to figure how to code it in xamarin. I think it may be a small problem that I might've missed out, but if anybody can share their code to show the info window based on the marker's position, I would be very glad. I'm open to any other suggestions and best solutions you guys may have thought of.

Hope you guys can help me, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The `GoogleMap` class has a `InfoWindowClick` event that you should hook up to listen to click events on the Info Window.

```cs
gmap.InfoWindowClick += HandleInfoWindowClick;

private void HandleInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
{
    var marker = eventArgs.Marker;
    // do stuff...
}
```

This will create a single event handler that reacts to all markers.

Xamarin has a nice sample on [how to use Google Maps on GitHub in their samples repo.](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/MapsAndLocationDemo_v3/)